# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I change this code so I don't receive the above error?

Here is the full error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/bestc165/public_html/opinuo.com/stream.php on line 10

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bestc165_opinuo', 'opinuo');

$sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM debates LIMIT 2  order by ts ';

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql_string );

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $name =  $row['name'];
    $text =  $row['text'];
?>

<h2><?php echo $name;?></h2>
<p><?php echo $text;?></p>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Replace `fetch_array()` with `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Thanks, but I still have an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/bestc165/public_html/opinuo.com/stream.php on line 10

Comment: one argument is missing in `mysqli_connect` function

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` comes after `ORDER BY`

Change your query to

```
$sql_string = 'SELECT * FROM debates ORDER BY ts LIMIT 2';
```

`mysqli_query` returns `FALSE` on failure so your `$result` is not an object but a `boolean` thus your error.

Update

As mentioned in the comments, make sure to pass the database name in the connection

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');
```

Or use [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

```
mysqli_select_db($link, "databaseName");
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives me the same error. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: First make sure you have successfully connected to the database and if you haven't misspelled any column names.

Comment: How do I make $result an object instead? Thanks!! And I am connected to the database and I didn't misspell anything (double checked).

Comment: did you try to run the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I did now and I found that I misspelled tc (I wrote it as ts). But I still have the error. 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/bestc165/public_html/opinuo.com/stream.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//Other code here

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_string );

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

?>

    <h2><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $row['text'];?></p>

<?php

}

?>
```

No need to use extra `loop` to show the output.